# How to make TeamCity only clean up certain files

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.0

Is it possible to make TeamCity only clean up certain files upon fetching files from my git repo? I modify one file as a build step, and thus always need a clean version of that file. However, it's really unnecessary to fetch the whole repo everytime because usually only a few files are modified (thus, I'd rather not use the 'Clean all files before build' command).

Thanks!

To clarify, lets say I have the following structure:
- index.html
- js/script.js
- js/plugins.js

I only want to *always* (regardless if any change has happened) to checkout index.html. The files in the js folder I only want to replace whenever any updates on them have happened.

Comment: What version of TeamCity are you using?

Comment: What source control are you using?

Comment: I'm sorry I missed this comment for such a long time - anyways: git

Answer (score 5):

If you are using TeamCity 6.5 or above you can use the [Build Files Cleaner (Swabra) Build Feature](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Build+Files+Cleaner+%28Swabra%29). Once you have added it your build steps and run clean build it will clean any new unversioned files generated during the build either before the new build starts or at the end of the current build.

I personally prefer to run it before the new build starts as it allows you to look at any of the output when trying to work out why something went wrong.

Basically it makes sure that there is nothing in the build agents work folder that was not pulled from the repository before each build.

Comment: Almost! Unless I'm mistaken, this actually doesn't update only the necessary files. If any change on index.html is detected, the whole directory is still cleaned. index.html will always be updated (by build script) so I always want to fetch a new version of index.html. However, when I do this I don't want e.g. js/script.js to be fetched unless it was updated. (And as always, appreciate you trying to answer!)

Comment: +1 This is a good technique if you do want everything cleaned, shame it is not sufficient for your needs Carl.